# Workaround for bugs in Python packages

Tags: python, package

I recently had the following problem: I'm developing a numerical library in Python (called `spuq`) that needs `scipy` at its core. Now one of the functions in scipy, its called `btdtri`, had a bug for a certain tuple of input parameters. This bug, however, is now fixed in scipy version 0.9 according to the developers of scipy. So in my code I have something like this:

```
import scipy

def foo(a, b, c):
  if scipy.__version__>=(0, 9):
      return btdtri(a, b, c)
  else:
      return my_fixed_btdtri(a, b, c)
```

This works, however, I don't really like to litter my code with bug fixes for third party packages. I would rather have that contained in one module, that implements the workaround, and have all the other of my modules uses the patched module automatically.

Now my question is: what would be the best practice to handle cases like this in general? E.g. write my own `spuq.contrib.scipy` and say there

```
from scipy import *
if __version__ < (0, 9):
  btdtri = my_fixed_btdtri
```

and instead of importing `scipy` import `spuq.contrib.scipy` everywhere? I think that's complicated and easy to forget (and probably unpythonic and ugly). Maybe there is a way to "hook" automatically into the package loading and modify the `scipy` module directly so that every other package sees only the patched up package? I think this problem is quite common, so probably there should be some 'best-practices' around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could "monkey patch" the scipy module.  Somewhere in your initialization code, do

```
import scipy.special
if scipy.version.version < "0.9.0":
    scipy.special.btdtri = my_btdtri
```

Since modules are imported only once, there will be only one module `scipy.special`, and all other modules will only see the monkey-patched version.

Monkey patching is often seen as useful for testing, but not for production code.  In this case, though, I think it is fine since you don't really change the behaviour of the package -- you are fixing a confirmed bug.

Comment: So where would you do that? In the main package's ``__init__`` module?

Comment: You need to make sure the code is executed before the function is called or imported using `from scipy.version import btdtri`.  (You shouldn't be doing the latter anyway.)  Where this place is depends on the structure of your application.

Comment: I don't really like this approach, as it changes the `scipy` module for any code that imports both `scipy` and the OP's code. With some conditional import tricks, the `btdtri` used by client code may differ from call to call.

Comment: @larsmans: There are cases where this might happen.  But I don't see how having consistently the buggy version is better than almost always having the fixed version.

Comment: @larsmans: It is very unlikely that client code of spuq directly calls `btdtri()`. If it does, it will most likely get the fixed version.  If it does strange imports and ends up with the buggy version, it will consistently crash -- nothing irreproducible happening here.  You wouldn't recommend people not to fix bugs in their own library because errors in client code wouldn't be reproducible any more, would you? :)

Comment: Well, if you're as big as MS you can even put your bugs into ISO standards and make everybody else implement them, too. But until I'm as big as them, I fear I still have to fix mine ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to make a module, say `fixes`, that exports the fixed version or the external version of `btdtri` depending on the SciPy version, as in your example. It can be done even simpler:

```
if scipy.version.version < (0,9,0):
    def btdtri(...):
        # whatever
else:
    btdtri = scipy.btdtri
```

This has the advantage over your version that code checking tools like `pyflakes` won't choke on the `import *` and that you don't need to fetch all of the SciPy API from the `fixes` module, just the part that needs fixing (remember: explicit is better than implicit).